# Is senior cat food OK for my young cat?

Tags: cats, diet, junior-pets, cat-food

I have two cats, one three years old and the other 13. I want to change the older cat to eating an expensive cat food for senior cats; both cats eat from the same bowl.

Is it okay for the young cat to eat senior cat food?

Comment: Senior cat food will not harm a 3 year old cat, but it will not be ideal either, as nutrients, calories and fiber content are geared towards the needs of senior cats. I'd consider microchip-controlled feeders, if the food is really expensive the investment isn't much over time, and you're always prepared (i.e. cats are used to the feeders) if a cat needs specific food for medical reasons at some point.